# Debian 3.2: Could not connect to Wireless network

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, debian

Debian version: Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u1 i686 GNU/Linux

I run Debian 7 Wheezy on Leveno G500 laptop computer. I was trying to connect to wireless network shared from Windows 7 Desktop computer.

I can see the network in the available network list but it is grayed out. I could not click on the network to connect to the network. Can anyone here help me please?

Comment: Debian 3.2 didn't exist; 3.1 was released in 2005. You're running Debian 7 (Wheezy) with Linux 3.2 as the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

First edit your /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkMnager.conf and change [ifupdown] managed=true, to be able for modify.
Then check your /etc/network/interfaces to look like:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

As for your wifi please make sure you have "wireless-tools" installed, and also provide us the output of `lspci -nn|grep Network` or anything else to see what wireless card is your lappy using, so we can be able to suggest you what firmware you need.
If you use a broadcom card please check these options:
https://wiki.debian.org/bcm43xx
https://wiki.debian.org/wl